# Declaring a variable using a select statement

Tags: sql

I'm trying to declare a value to make my query run a faster.

I want to store `@driver_collected`, so I can query it below - I hope I'm doing it right.

It's so that I can give a better status online for our customers, separating the difference between 'Ready for Delivery' and 'Out for Delivery'

```sql
declare @driver_collected int;
set @driver_collected = (select max(x.recieved) from entry_extra x inner join entry e2 on e2.entry_id = x.entry_id where e2.link_entry_id = e.entry_id),

select e.entry_id,e.taxpoint_date,
case
when e.delivery_method_id <> 3 @driver_collected is null
then 'Ready for Dispatch'
when e.delivery_method_id <> 3 @driver_collected is not null
then 'Out For Delivery'
else 'Test'
end
from entry e where e.entry_type in ('SORD','SRTN') and e.trader_id = 1203046
```

I'd expect my results to be:

```
entry_id,taxpoint_date, Ready for Dispatch / Out For Delivery'
```

I'm not experience enough to know where I'm getting it wrong, any advice really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error that you are seeing (but we do not, because you did not give that info here)  explains where you are getting wrong.

Comment: when e.delivery_method_id <> 3 *AND* @driver_collected is null

Comment: TIP, read the [docs about CASE WHEN....](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks Luuk, I've added the AND (I'd missed in error).

Getting the error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored the query slightly to remove your syntax error, in your first query you refer to alias `e` which you don't have, assuming this should be `x`

```
declare @driver_collected int;
select @driver_collected=max(x.recieved)
from entry_extra x
inner join entry e2 on e2.entry_id = x.entry_id
  and e2.link_entry_id = x.entry_id 

select e.entry_id,e.taxpoint_date,
case
  when e.delivery_method_id <> 3 and @driver_collected is null
  then 'Ready for Dispatch'
  when e.delivery_method_id <> 3 and @driver_collected is not null
  then 'Out For Delivery'
else 'Test'
end as DeliveryStatus
from entry e 
where e.entry_type in ('SORD','SRTN') and e.trader_id = 1203046
```

Comment: Thanks Stu, Thats exaclty what I needed.
My query now runs in under 1s, thank you!